# foreach usage in php when i have multiple items

Tags: php

My list of file format include :

```
mac@test.net user01@test.net 106627
mac@test.net user02@test.net 105873
```

My important columns is column **2** and **3** , now how can i say to `foreach` put column **2** for `email` and column **3** for `password` ?

before i use :

```
$items = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

but i think it should be change .

Comment: its good but can gimme some example for my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply loop the lines from the file and explode on a space (that appears to be what is defining the columns):

```
$items = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($items as $item) {
    $columns = explode(' ', $item);
    echo "Email: {$columns[1]} Password: {$columns[2]}";
}
```